# Update notification in notification center IOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am designing a push notification system for an IOS application. There are some requirements i want to fulfil.

1. Be able to change the title and body of the push locally.
2. Have the notification center only display only the most recent notification per identifier. So if the device receives 2 push notification request with the same identifier, the second one should replace the first one in the notification center.
3. Ability to send the push even when the app is forcefully killed.

**Using a `UNNotificationServiceExtension`**

When using a ServiceExtension, I can modify the contents but I can't change the request identifier because it is a get only property. As a result, my notification center doesn't replace old notifications with new ones.

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if var bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here... sweet!
        bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
        //resolveNotificationContent(content: &bestAttemptContent)

        //getDeliveredNotifications always returns an empty array of notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications{ notifications in
            print("notifications: \(notifications)")
        }

        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

**Using Silent Notification**

My other idea is to send a silent notification and manually create the "Non-Silent" notification locally like so.

```
//Called when the user recieves a notifiation and the app is in the background
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    log.info()
    defer {
        completionHandler(.noData)
    }

    //if app is active, return
    if application.applicationState == .active {
        return
    }

    guard let content = PushNotification.createNotificationContent(from: userInfo) else {
        return
    }

    guard let notificationData = content.userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any] else {
        log.error("failed to convert 'aps' value to Dict<String:Any>")
        return
    }

    let pushData = PushNotification.resolveNotification(from: notificationData)
    var identifier = ""
    if pushData != nil {
        identifier = pushData!.getIdentifier()
    }

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        self.log.error(error)
    }
}
```

Problem is that my silent notification is never delivered when the app is forcefully killed (makes sense).

Is there any way I can fulfil all 3 requirements?

Comment: Short answer; No.  If the user kills your app you cannot post the local notification.  I believe in this instance iOS will display the content of the push if there is any, so the user would only get the default push content, you would not be able to customise it

Comment: Thanks. When using a `UNNotificationServiceExtension ` is it possible to change the request identifier so that a newer request will replace an older one?

Comment: Can you specify the [apns-collapse-id](https://medium.com/the-guardian-mobile-innovation-lab/how-to-replace-the-content-of-an-ios-notification-2d8d93766446) in your push?

Comment: This works. Note `apns-collapse-id` is available when using [APNs notification api](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1).

Comment: @SomeGuyFortune did you get any luck on this

Comment: @hussain, I actually don't remember the problem I was trying to solve. I don't do ios development anymore and I don't have access to the source code. But I do remember using the apns-collapse-id in some way.

Comment: Thanks @SomeGuyFortune actually we are using firebase and adding apps-collapse-id don't work there. Thanks for the suggestion.